# Error Web page not available

Tags: google-chrome, websites, mozilla

I am using Ubuntu 14.10 and always getting the error web page not available when I try to access certain web pages like http://www.edx.org, http://www.coursera.org and many more on chrome and mozilla. can anybody tell me why I'm getting such error with chrome and mozilla and how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pinging the website:

```
ping www.edx.org
```

If that doesn't work, try resolving the domain:

```
nslookup www.edx.org
```

If that doesn't work either, test if you have internet connectivity at all:

```
ping 8.8.8.8 # public Google DNS server
```

If all commands failed, you're apparently not connected to the internet.
If the all but the last command fail try [changing your DNS server to Google's public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using?hl=en).
If only the first command fails continue diagnosing your problem using traceroute:

```
traceroute www.edx.org
```

Some tips on diagnosing connection problems: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-network-diagnose-tools.html